# Amazon DynamoDB multiple scan conditions with multiple BeginsWith

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I have table in Amazon DynamoDB with partition key and range key.

Table structure

```
Subscriber ID (partition key) | Item Id (Range Key) | Date        |...
123                           | P_345               | some date 1 | ...
123                           | I_456               | some date 2 |
123                           | A_678               | some date 3 | ...
```

Now I want to retrieve the data from the table using `QueryAsync` C# library with multiple scan conditions.

- HashKey = 123
- condition 1; Date is between 'some date 1' and 'some date 2'
- condition 2. Range Key begins_with I_ and P_

Is there any way which I can achieve this using c# dynamoDB APIs?
Please help

Answer (score 3):

You'll need to do the following (I'm not a C# expert, but you can use the following instructions to find the right C# syntax to do it):

1. Because you are looking for a specific hashkey, this will be a `Query` request, not a `Scan`.
2. You have a `begins_with()` condition on the range key. You specify that using the `KeyConditionExpression` parameter to the `Query`. The `KeyConditionExpression` will ask for HashKey=123 AND begins_with(RangeKey,"P_").
3. However, `KeyConditionExpression` does not allow an "OR" (rangekey begins with either "P_" or "I_"). You'll just need to run two separate queries - one with "I_" and one with "P_" (you can even do the two queries in parallel, if you wish).
4. The date is not one of the key columns, so you will need to filter it with a `FilterExpression` parameter to the query. Note that filtering only happens in the last step, after DynamoDB already read all the items matching the `KeyConditionExpression` above (this may increase your costs if filtering removes a lot of items and you will still pay for them).